# Hadoop: Image processing of colored images

Tags: hadoop, image-processing, mapreduce

I have a very huge number of colored images. And I want to process the images in such a way that that whenever the average of the RGB values of an image exceeds a particular number, I want to output that imageid and it's timestamp so that I can locate this time in the actual video. I was reading about image processing and people have suggested converting images to sequence files or using HIPI framework. I do not get how can I extract the image information from the sequence file? And HIPI framework has not been updated and doesn't work with the current hadoop version. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: @Tariq : Any ideas on this? Since I saw your comments in many of the image processing related questions, thought you could help

Comment: @Tariq : Will HIPI work with the latest version of hadoop?